# How to return groovy map keys

Tags: groovy

I have a map of attributes been passed to a taglib and want to find only the keys that start with "data-" in them.

Example:
in my **gsp** file I use this

```
<me:myInput name="my-name" id="my-name" data-minlength="5" data-len="1"/>
```

**taglib**

```
static namespace = "me"
Closure myInput = { attrs ->
  def dataMap = attrs.keySet()
}
```

So the above will add all the keys to the dataMap. I just want the ones that have 'data-' in front of them added not the others.

I also want to strip the 'data-' before I store it in the dataMap.
The data map should end up looking like this.

```
dataMap = ['required', 'len']
```

Anyone know how I would go about this in groovy.

Comment: What you show as "dataMap" isn't a Map at all, its a List.  I am struggling to make sense of your question.  Further, your initialization of map doesn't compile at all.  Hmmm.

Comment: Sorry let me try explain it out more.

Comment: The original Map code compiles if you just remove the curly braces.

Comment: The question makes sense to me.  `dataMap` is a peculiar name for the variable, maybe `matchingKeys` or something like that makes more sense, but the question as written is coherent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you could slice this up.

```
matchingKeys = map.keySet().findAll { it.startsWith('data-') }.collect { it[5..-1] }

matchingKeys = map.keySet().findAll { it.startsWith('data-')}*.getAt([5..-1])

matchingKeys = map.keySet().findAll { it.startsWith('data-') }.collect { it - 'data-' }
```

I hope that helps.